# u1sync: error: --oauth requires a key and secret together in the form KEY:SECRET

Tags: ubuntu-one

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on a headless server.

I've set up an Ubuntu One account.

I have installed `ubuntuone-sso-login.py` and generated a key with it.

I have run:

```
u1sync --init --oauth=[here I've put the key with cut and past from the step before] [directory name]
```

And I always get this error message :

```
u1sync: error: --oauth requires a key and secret together in the  form KEY:SECRET
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We have solved it, but I want to share it :

```
#!/bin/bash

OAUTH_TOKEN=Ffdxxxxxx
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET=oDxxx

OAUTH=$OAUTH_TOKEN:$OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET

/usr/bin/u1sync --oauth $OAUTH
```

I also had to remove the (=) equal after the --oauth

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use this guide to use the current Ubuntu One client headless:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Headless